# Como adicionar uma Search bar na Header da minha home (Ionic + AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Pretendo criar um Serach Bar na minha home estou com dificuldades alguém pode me ajudar ? vou deixar aqui o meu Controller e a minha Views a Home .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para filtrar a sua lista, basta usar o `filter`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filtrar" ng-model="filtro">

<a ng-repeat="lista in listas | filter:filtro:strict">
```

Veja mais: [AngulasJS Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Valeuuuuu mano deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo como:

```
<div class="bar bar-subheader bar-light">
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="text" size="100" ng-model="q" placeholder="Procurar" />
            </label>
        </div>
```

**E no ng-repeat de seu formulário:** *| filter:q*

Ou utilize este plugin:

http://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-filter-bar